# Need help using SQL expression with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to omit a column from updating if the value is empty, but would like it to update if its not empty.

So far I came with the following expression

```
$foo = NULL;


$query = "UPDATE test SET column1 = IF('{$foo}'='',coloumn1,'' )";
$result = mysqli_query($handle,$query);
if(!$result){
    echo mysqli_error($handle);
}
```

The problem that I am facing is when I set $foo to an actual value coloumn1 is empty again.

I am not sure why. If anyone can help me understand this, I would really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: `column1`? `coloumn1`? Which is it?

Comment: You probably want to do the test in the php code, not the SQL code (if you're only updating that column).

Comment: I agree with @jcaron. Apart from being just simpler, it is performance-wise better...

Comment: @JovanPerovic When I use a PHP script it will just set the column to empty. This was just a sample code. On my actual code I have 20 coloumns

Answer (score 0):

If your value is indeed null (not empty), you might want to consider the use of `COALESCE`:

```
UPDATE test SET column1 = COALESCE(?,column1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have never heard of the COALESCE function. In the example above, $foo can sometimes be NULL or sometimes have a value. What does the question mark do in that place?

Comment: The question mark is a placeholder for your SQL statement. You should never include variables directly in SQL statements, but use parameter placeholders and parameter binding via `prepare` and `bind_params`.